# Application Loader - Apple's upload was not successful... But it was!

Tags: iphone, upload, itunes, application-loader

Hey guys, having a "what the hell" moment here, I just uploaded an update and it gave me an ITMS - 4000 error, possibly because of a bad bundle name. Okay, I can fix that.

Wait a minute...

I just got an email 2 minutes ago saying that "the status of your application has changed to waiting for review."

Huh? Anyone know why? I mean, I'm not complaining, just comfused.

Comment: Random glitch in the universe? Have you tried rebooting it?

Comment: Well, it's uploaded so I'm just going to roll with it. But when apple starts glitching that stupidly, we know the apocalypse is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to investigate so you dont waste time. Your app could stay in queue for several days only to be rejected for an issue you could have fixed sooner. Just because the app was uploaded successfully, doesn't mean it is good to go; I would investigate further.

Comment: I just contacted support and they got it going again.